# How is DEP(Data Execution Prevention) bypassed?

Tags: security, exploit, dep

What are some ways that Data Execution Prevention can be bypassed? I would appreciate if someone could go in depth on how it would work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Daniel. This forum does not handle braod requests like this or "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @micstr I never asked to be recommended anything off-site. My problem is that I don't know how DEP can be bypassed, and to solve it, I have asked this question.

Comment: I was just pointing out that broad questions like this that without source code tend not to get good responses(see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Lets hope you get some response.  Whilst you wait - Have you looked at http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=DEP or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581581/how-to-disable-dep?

Comment: @micstr Thank you for showing me that!

Comment: JIT spraying can bypass DEP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840087/why-cant-javascript-shellcode-exploits-be-fixed-via-data-execution-prevention/29171692#29171692

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a hard question.
I am not sure you are asking you want to disable it or bypass it.
If you want to disable it, compile it with `-z execstack` parameter
Like following command.

`gcc main.c -z execstack`

If you want to bypass, you could try a technique called [ROP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming)